# valgrind reports std::string leaking when I explicitly release the memory

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a number of unit tests which are run through valgrind.

There are 15 tests in total, all use the same base class (`Foo`) which has a `std::string` member (`value_`) and a virtual destructor.

All unit tests pass, the destructor is called 15 times, but valgrind reports a leak for that string 8 times (for 8 of the 15 tests).

All 8 reported leaks refer to the same string

```
==30881== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 8
==30881==    at 0x4A07D73: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:332)
==30881==    by 0x3AEF09C3C8: allocate (new_allocator.h:89)
==30881==    by 0x3AEF09C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.tcc:608)
==30881==    by 0x3AEF09DDA9: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:480)
==30881==    by 0x3AEF09DF6B: std::string::_M_replace_safe(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:685)
==30881==    by 0xBFB67D: test::TestFoo::TestFoo() (test_foo.h:26)
```

Line 26 in `test_foo.h` is where the string is assigned:

```
TestFoo()
{
    value_ = "test"; // line 26
}
```

I have added the following "check" / "hack" in the `Foo` destructor (base class of `TestFoo`):

```
virtual ~Foo()
{
    LOG_TRACE("value capacity(%lu)", value_.capacity());

    std::string().swap(value_); // force memory to be released

    LOG_TRACE("value capacity(%lu)", value_.capacity());
}
```

In my log files I verify that the `Foo` destructor is called 15 times, and for each time, the capacity drops to 0.

```
|01:13:59.477486350| {TRACE} [Foo::~Foo] value capacity(4)
|01:13:59.479293212| {TRACE} [Foo::~Foo] value capacity(0)
```

The environment in which this is failing:

- CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
- g++ (GCC) 5.2.1 20150902 (Red Hat 5.2.1-2)
- valgrind-3.11.0
- Linux version 2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c1bl.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jul 12 14:17:22 UTC 2017

Note that on a different machine this failure doesn't happen (Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5.4, but the same version of valgrind)

**Questions:**

Is it possible to fix this so that valgrind doesn't think the memory is leaked, without resorting to a suppression file?

Comment: Why do you show constructor of TestFoo and destructor of Foo? If value_ is regular member variable of type `std::string` its memory should be release without any tricks

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky the string is a protected member of `Foo`, and is assigned in the subclass `TestFoo`. The memory for the string's internal buffer will be allocated in `TestFoo`'s constructor, and deallocated in `Foo`'s destructor. It is a regular member variable of type `std::string`, and so yes, I agree, it's memory should be released without any tricks... hence this question

Comment: Could you show the minimal sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I will have a crack at creating one - obviously the existing code is significantly more complicated

Comment: Yes but chances are that by stripping out what you think is not relevant to the problem you'll find the source of the report